# Excel sorting unexpected results

Tags: excel, sorting

I need to implement a custom sort in a web application table like Excel sort. I came accross the following article: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/322067/how-to-correctly-sort-alphanumeric-data-in-excel

According to this it sorts alphanumeric values character by character, from left to right. But I faced some strange results having the following values: a, A, abc, ABC. Excel sorts them like this (Sort A to Z):

```
ABC
a
A
abc
```

So why upper 'A' comes **after** lower 'a' but upper 'ABC' comes **before** lower 'abc'?

And this is Sort Z to A:

```
ABC
abc
a
A
```

I have Excel 2013 if it does matter.

Comment: @pnuts What results do you have?

Comment: hm.. looks like you're right. I entered manually and get the correct sorting. But when I then select this and click (Z<A) I get: 'abc', 'ABC', 'a', 'A'. I assume it should be exact reverse of (A>Z): 'ABC', 'abc', 'A', 'a'.

Comment: I cannot reproduce it when I enter all values manually, but **IT DOES** reproduce when I copy it from your question. I suspect there are some invisible Unicode chars inside.

Comment: @Taosique I cannot reproduce it either when I enter this manually. What do you receive when you then select all values and click reverse (Z<A) option?

Answer (score 1):

Not quite a solution, but I found the problem cause. When you press `A>Z` and `Z>A` buttons, Excel performs sorting by *guessing* (I couldn't find logic) whether your data has a header row, so `ABC` becomes a header row and does not participate in sorting. You can see it yourself by opening an advanced sort dialog and looking at the headers checkbox. Sometimes it is set, sometimes not depending on the value in the first row.

**UPDATE:** I think I found the logic. Excel considers the value a header row if it *has no lowercase letters* (checked it for Cyrillic script as well):

```
ABC - header
abc - not header
Abc - not header
ABC$1# - header
ABc$1# - not header
БГД - header
Бгд - not header
```

[image]

Comment: If tested on freshly opened Excel, yes, it's a guess, individual for each column. Otherwise the setting from last performed sort will apply for any column.

Comment: There is also an option 'Case sensitive' (Sort&Filter->Custom Sort->Options). When I tick it on I get an expected results. So looks like by default the sorting is case insensitive.